# Photo Collage with JQuery

Tags: jquery, flash, photo

I would like to develop a Photo Collage that similar to http://www.fotor.com/features/collage.html with JQuery

**Edited**: I have searched several days. Fotor Collage uses Flash. I also tried with some form builders as http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/07/jquery-form-builder-plugin/. I modified these according to my needs and export the form to XML file for later use in another. The app currently support only typical html elements as text. I still need to add photos and movies.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: eh, I would like to learn how to develop these things... Is there any libraries available or opensource?

Comment: What did you find when you searched for it?

Comment: uhm, I did searched several days already. Fotor Collage uses Flash. I also tried with some form builders as botsko.net/blog/2009/04/07/jquery-form-builder-plugin. I did modified these according to my needs and export the form to XML file for later use in another app. However, the most updated version of botsko supports only some typical html elements. I still need to add something like movies... and able to use frame templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are trying to do 2 different things:

1. on CLIENT: drag and drop effect with pics and documents
2. on SERVER: upload that file (maybe with AJAX. check out [this plugin](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax))

For the CLIENT part you could use [jQuery UI droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/).

Once the file is dropped (using [droppable events](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)), you can upload that file. code example:

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) { alert("here i can upload my file"); }
});
```

Here it is an example for beginning coding: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager.

Comment: How can I add a photo box with the ability to upload a photo into it so that we can change different photos? I do not know much about these things so difficult to choose a right search keyword. Thank much for your help.

Comment: maybe because you're confusing 2 different topics. check out my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 canvas, you can easy develop photo collage maker on website. Like [FotoJet](https://www.fotojet.com/), it's developed base on reactjs/jquery and bootstrap etc.

The most popular library is [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/), you can develop a your app just with it.